# How to expand all steps in Material UI stepper for printing page?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a React component that makes use of Material UI stepper.
The requirement is that the data has to be printable as well. When you print though, all the steps should be expanded and have to be printed. This is against the default behaviour of a stepper. @media print does not seem to work as the Stepper is controlled with 'active' attribute to toggle display and not just CSS class. Has anyone achieved this before? Material UI components with different behaviour for printing only? Let me know thanks.

Basic stepper example - https://codesandbox.io/s/rm5713kkln

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a project with the same requirements and couldn't find any solution with react component level.
However, I could find a solution from redux store level. (If you are using a store).

- I added my multi-step form into a redux form (https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/) [btw you can do this without the redux form library]
- then the data added into the store was retrieved to a final summary page. (final step of stepper)
- since the summary page has all the data I could use this data with jsPDF (like client-side PDF generator)[https://mrrio.github.io/]
- finally, I found this approach was way cleaner than using the HTML into pdf since I can change and improve the look and UI of the pdf as I wish. (it doesn't depends on the HTML UI, only on the data)

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately I had to step away from MUI and created a CSS only accordion with similar behaviour and use the @media print for print styles.